# Call to a member function query() on null in

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error

I got this error when I am trying to enter my site.

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\serverfiles\core\functions\general.php on line 321"

**Code:**

```
     /* Function to return all the settings table */
    
    function settings_data() {
         global $database;

         $result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE `id` = 1");
         $data   = $result->fetch_object();

         return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Your connection isn't connecting.

Comment: Make sure `$database` object is defined first, and connected. Why not pass $database to the function as argument, instead of doing global;?